# Node.js and app variables

Tags: node.js

I'm very new on node.js but I developed in java so, now, I'm trying to create a crud web app using node.js.

I was studying/modifying this tutorial:
http://teknosains.com/i/restful-crud-example-with-nodejs-and-mysql

Now I can do all CRUD operation into user table, now I would like to replay these operations for another table so I moved all operations into a sub directory (called app) and in a file called user.js and the "views" file into a subdirectory called "user".

At this moment all works correctly because I insert only the reference of the "user module" into "main file".

I would extract some parts, like the connection instance, to a "super" class so I can call all times the super class withoud copying the connection variables and the web server instance.
Is it possible? And if the answer is yes, how?

Comment: Can you show us some of the code? It's very difficult to see what could be wrong from your comments alone.

Comment: @ jakerella : I did an "abstract" question because I don't have any issue! I would know if I could using something to don't repeat parts of code, like the connection instance, in all file :-)

Comment: In that case, I don't think this is a proper question for SO.. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me see if I understand your question: you want to know how you can create an abstraction in your code that will let you pass connection variables once and then allow you to interact with the abstraction to perform REST actions.

As you're coming from Java, I recommend you read up on [prototypical inheritance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain) and the [class keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) in ES2016.

Also take a look at [Sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/v3/), which is the common SQL object-relational mapper for Node.js.

All of which should answer your questions on how to implement class inheritance-like behavior and how to manage your MySQL tables without repeating yourself.

Comment: Thanks! Make sure to accept my response if it answers your question.